# How to enable longer file path in IntelliJ's find in path preview panel

Tags: intellij-idea

Using 'Find in Path' in intelliJ we can preview search results easily by looking into files found. Is it possible to make upper panel (one that displays files found) show longer(deeper) source path. 
Currently it shows

```
parentFolder\fileFound
```

or

```
parentsParentFolder\[..]\fileFound
```

if intelliJ find parentFolder to be a common name.

I want to make preview panel showed me file source up to n-th level like

```
n-thParentFolder\n-1-thParentFolder\...\parentFolder\fileFound
```

Is it possible?

EDIT: providing screenshot for better understanding

[image: Find in path preview]

Looking into screenshot provided, I cannot tell the difference between 1st-4th row and 3th-6th row.

Comment: Sharing a screenshot may make it easier to understand what your current setup is and what to look for. Also please let us know what IJ version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

That's not currently possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174542 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified of any progress.